# Is it possible to create a table like this one?

Tags: tables, cell, merge

[image: table]
I want the cells to be vertical middle aligned.

Comment: Yes, this is possible, but note that in many western countries a table like this would be considered bad typography (so many rules are ugly). Take a look at the [`multirow`](https://texdoc.org/pkg/multirow) package.

Comment: And read https://texdoc.org/pkg/booktabs if you want a sense of why you maybe shouldn't want to do this. :)

Comment: Can you update your question title to be more representative of what you're after? "How to do this?" isn't helpful when viewing question snippets in searches. Can you do that?

Answer (score 6):

In OpTeX, we can use `\vspan` macro, as described in the [documentation](https://petr.olsak.net/ftp/olsak/optex/optex-doc.pdf), page 16.

```
\fontfam[lm]
\sans\rm

\table{4{c|}}{\crl
   \vspan2{x=1} & abc & xyz & asd, \crlp{2-3}
                & bcd & qwe & pqr  \crl
   \vspan2{x=2} & abc & xyz & asd, \crlp{2-3}
                & bcd & qwe & pqr  \crl
   \vspan2{x=3} & abc & xyz & asd, \crlp{2-3}
                & bcd & qwe & pqr  \crl
   \vspan2{x=4} & abc & xyz & asd, \crlp{2-3}
                & bcd & qwe & pqr  \crl
}
\bye
```

Comment: Note, that the question doesn't mention LaTeX, so the answers can be based on various TeX formats. There isn't LaTeX only. So, the negative votes are unair. Maybe, somebody dislikes OpTeX.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a solution that employs a single `tabular` environment.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}    % for '\extrarowheight' parameter and 'w' column type
\usepackage{multirow} % for '\multirow' macro
\usepackage{arev}     % optional: sans-serif text and math fonts

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\setlength\extrarowheight{2pt} % default: 0pt

\begin{tabular}{ wc{1.5cm} | wl{1.5cm} | wl{1.5cm} | wc{1.5cm} | }
\hline
\multirow{2.2}{*}{x=1} & abc & xyz & asd, \\
\cline{2-3}
                       & bcd & qwe & pqr  \\
\hline
\multirow{2.2}{*}{x=2} & abc & xyz & asd, \\
\cline{2-3}
                       & bcd & qwe & pqr  \\
\hline
\end{tabular}

\end{center}

\end{document}
```

Comment: The solution given above uses a uniform width of 1.5cm for all 4 columns. Obviously, you're free to choose other, possibly more suitable, column width values.

Answer (score 2):

Solution with use of the `tabularray` package:

```
\documentclass[margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tabularray} 
\usepackage{arev}     % optional: sans-serif text and math fonts

\begin{document}
\begin{tblr}{hline{odd} = solid, hline{even} = {2-3}{solid}, 
             vline{2-Z} = solid, 
             colspec = {Q[c, wd=15mm, mode=math] *{3}{Q[c, wd=15mm]}}, 
             cell{odd}{1} = {r=2}{} % multi row cells
             }
x=1 & abc & xyz & asd, \\
    & bcd & qwe & pqr  \\
x=2 & abc & xyz & asd, \\
    & bcd & qwe & pqr  \\
x=3 & abc & xyz & asd, \\
    & bcd & qwe & pqr  \\
x=4 & abc & xyz & asd, \\
    & bcd & qwe & pqr  \\
\end{tblr}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Addendum:**
or by small variation of above MWE where in last column are used multirow cells too:

```
\documentclass[margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage{arev}     

\begin{document}
\begin{tblr}{hlines, vline{2-Z} = solid, 
             colspec = {Q[c, wd=15mm, mode=math] *{3}{Q[c, wd=15mm]}}, 
             cell{odd}{1,Z} = {r=2}{} % multi row cells
             }
y=1 & abc & xyz & {asd,\\ pqr}  \\
    & bcd & qwe &               \\
y=2 & abc & xyz & {asd,\\ pqr}  \\
    & bcd & qwe &               \\
y=3 & abc & xyz & {asd,\\ pqr}  \\
    & bcd & qwe &               \\
y=4 & abc & xyz & {asd,\\ pqr}  \\
    & bcd & qwe &               \\
\end{tblr}

\end{document}
```

Produced table is similar as before:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution with `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix`.

```
\documentclass[margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{nicematrix} 

\begin{document}

\begin{NiceTabular}{c|c|c|c|}[hlines]
\Block{2-1}{x=1} & abc & xyz & \Block{2-1}{asd, \\ pqr} \\
    & bcd & qwe \\
\Block{2-1}{x=2} & abc & xyz & \Block{2-1}{asd, \\ pqr} \\
    & bcd & qwe \\
\Block{2-1}{x=3} & abc & xyz & \Block{2-1}{asd, \\ pqr} \\
    & bcd & qwe \\
\Block{2-1}{x=4} & abc & xyz & \Block{2-1}{asd, \\ pqr} \\
    & bcd & qwe \\
\end{NiceTabular}

\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the above code]

Answer (score 0):

You can probably achieve this by nesting tabular-environments - each cell itself could be a tabular-environment on it own, tabular-environments in leftmost-column vertically `[t]`-aligned, tabular-environments in other columns vertically `[c]`-aligned:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\begin{document}

\sffamily\selectfont

\begin{tabular}{|@{}c@{}|@{}c@{}|@{}c@{}|@{}c@{}|}%
\hline \begin{tabular}[t]{c}$\mathsf{x=1}$\end{tabular}%
&      \begin{tabular}[c]{l@{\hskip4\tabcolsep}}
       \rlap{abc}\hphantom{\vbox{\hbox{abc}\hbox{bcd}\hbox{a1b1c1}\hbox{b1c1d1}\hbox{a11b11c11}\hbox{b11c11d11}\hbox{a111b111c111}\hbox{b111c111d111}}}
       \\\hline 
       \rlap{bcd}\hphantom{\vbox{\hbox{abc}\hbox{bcd}\hbox{a1b1c1}\hbox{b1c1d1}\hbox{a11b11c11}\hbox{b11c11d11}\hbox{a111b111c111}\hbox{b111c111d111}}}
       \end{tabular}%
&      \begin{tabular}[c]{l@{\hskip4\tabcolsep}}
       \rlap{xyz}\hphantom{\vbox{\hbox{xyz}\hbox{qwe}\hbox{x1y1z1}\hbox{q1w1e1}\hbox{x11y11z11}\hbox{q11w11e11}\hbox{x111y111z111}\hbox{q111w111e111}}}
       \\\hline
       \rlap{qwe}\hphantom{\vbox{\hbox{xyz}\hbox{qwe}\hbox{x1y1z1}\hbox{q1w1e1}\hbox{x11y11z11}\hbox{q11w11e11}\hbox{x111y111z111}\hbox{q111w111e111}}}
       \end{tabular}%
&      \begin{tabular}[c]{r}asd,\\[\arrayrulewidth] pqr\end{tabular}%
\\
\hline \begin{tabular}[t]{c}$\mathsf{x=2}$\end{tabular}%
&      \begin{tabular}[c]{l@{\hskip4\tabcolsep}}
       \rlap{a1b1c1}\hphantom{\vbox{\hbox{abc}\hbox{bcd}\hbox{a1b1c1}\hbox{b1c1d1}\hbox{a11b11c11}\hbox{b11c11d11}\hbox{a111b111c111}\hbox{b111c111d111}}}
       \\\hline
       \rlap{b1c1d1}\hphantom{\vbox{\hbox{abc}\hbox{bcd}\hbox{a1b1c1}\hbox{b1c1d1}\hbox{a11b11c11}\hbox{b11c11d11}\hbox{a111b111c111}\hbox{b111c111d111}}}
       \end{tabular}%
&      \begin{tabular}[c]{l@{\hskip4\tabcolsep}}
       \rlap{x1y1z1}\hphantom{\vbox{\hbox{xyz}\hbox{qwe}\hbox{x1y1z1}\hbox{q1w1e1}\hbox{x11y11z11}\hbox{q11w11e11}\hbox{x111y111z111}\hbox{q111w111e111}}}
       \\\hline
       \rlap{q1w1e1}\hphantom{\vbox{\hbox{xyz}\hbox{qwe}\hbox{x1y1z1}\hbox{q1w1e1}\hbox{x11y11z11}\hbox{q11w11e11}\hbox{x111y111z111}\hbox{q111w111e111}}}
       \end{tabular}%
&      \begin{tabular}[c]{r}asd,\\[\arrayrulewidth] pqr\end{tabular}%
\\\hline \begin{tabular}[t]{c}$\mathsf{x=3}$\end{tabular}%
&      \begin{tabular}[c]{l@{\hskip4\tabcolsep}}
       \rlap{a11b11c11}\hphantom{\vbox{\hbox{abc}\hbox{bcd}\hbox{a1b1c1}\hbox{b1c1d1}\hbox{a11b11c11}\hbox{b11c11d11}\hbox{a111b111c111}\hbox{b111c111d111}}}
       \\\hline
       \rlap{b11c11d11}\hphantom{\vbox{\hbox{abc}\hbox{bcd}\hbox{a1b1c1}\hbox{b1c1d1}\hbox{a11b11c11}\hbox{b11c11d11}\hbox{a111b111c111}\hbox{b111c111d111}}}
       \end{tabular}%
&      \begin{tabular}[c]{l@{\hskip4\tabcolsep}}
       \rlap{x11y11z11}\hphantom{\vbox{\hbox{xyz}\hbox{qwe}\hbox{x1y1z1}\hbox{q1w1e1}\hbox{x11y11z11}\hbox{q11w11e11}\hbox{x111y111z111}\hbox{q111w111e111}}}
       \\\hline
       \rlap{q11w11e11}\hphantom{\vbox{\hbox{xyz}\hbox{qwe}\hbox{x1y1z1}\hbox{q1w1e1}\hbox{x11y11z11}\hbox{q11w11e11}\hbox{x111y111z111}\hbox{q111w111e111}}}
       \end{tabular}%
&      \begin{tabular}[c]{r}asd,\\[\arrayrulewidth] pqr\end{tabular}%
\\\hline \begin{tabular}[t]{c}$\mathsf{x=4}$\end{tabular}%
&      \begin{tabular}[c]{l@{\hskip4\tabcolsep}}
       \rlap{a111b111c111}\hphantom{\vbox{\hbox{abc}\hbox{bcd}\hbox{a1b1c1}\hbox{b1c1d1}\hbox{a11b11c11}\hbox{b11c11d11}\hbox{a111b111c111}\hbox{b111c111d111}}}
       \\\hline
       \rlap{b111c111d111}\hphantom{\vbox{\hbox{abc}\hbox{bcd}\hbox{a1b1c1}\hbox{b1c1d1}\hbox{a11b11c11}\hbox{b11c11d11}\hbox{a111b111c111}\hbox{b111c111d111}}}
       \end{tabular}%
&      \begin{tabular}[c]{l@{\hskip4\tabcolsep}}
       \rlap{x111y111z111}\hphantom{\vbox{\hbox{xyz}\hbox{qwe}\hbox{x1y1z1}\hbox{q1w1e1}\hbox{x11y11z11}\hbox{q11w11e11}\hbox{x111y111z111}\hbox{q111w111e111}}}
       \\\hline
       \rlap{q111w111e111}\hphantom{\vbox{\hbox{xyz}\hbox{qwe}\hbox{x1y1z1}\hbox{q1w1e1}\hbox{x11y11z11}\hbox{q11w11e11}\hbox{x111y111z111}\hbox{q111w111e111}}}
       \end{tabular}%
&      \begin{tabular}[c]{r}asd,\\[\arrayrulewidth] pqr\end{tabular}%
\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you decide to specify a width for table-columns, you don't need the combination of `\rlap` and `\hphantom` for ensuring equal widths for all tables in one column.